# Hide PhpStorm green left bar

Tags: phpstorm

I started using PhpStorm for my dev stuff however I don't understand what the green left scrollbar is and how to hide it!

[image: SCREENSHOT]

Comment: Add a screenshot plz

Comment: there is a screenshot

Comment: does it bother's when coding?

Comment: This is VCS Status for your code -- add/modified/deleted lines. You cannot disable it .. unless you disable VCS integration (git/mercurial/whatever) for this project as well.Other option is to remove/change the colors for those markers (edit your color scheme).

Comment: Thanks everyone!

As @LazyOne suggested, I just removed the Versioning Control from that.

You must de-register the project from within PhpStorm by going to Settings > Version Control and removing the project from the list

Answer (score 0):

This bar's color indicates VCS status since last commit.

- Green means that this line was added.
- Blue means, that this line was changed.
- Gray arrow pointing between lines where some code was removed.

Answer (score 0):

It is the line status that is showing you the recent changes.
Green means that you added a new line since the last synchronization.

https://www.jetbrains.com/help/phpstorm/2016.3/file-status-highlights.html

Answer (score 0):

The setting you are looking for is:

> Settings>Editor>Colors & Fonts>Diff & Merge

You can change colors there, but not disable them. One option is to try changing the colors to be simmilar to your theme's color.